# SQL Insert Statement, No error or exception, but data not inserted

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm working on a group project and one of the other group participants wrote one of the page's backend logic. I ran his code and to my surprise no errors, but also the data is not inserted into the database. I tried using a `try-catch` to force an exception out if there is one, but nothing. Any ideas to what might cause this?

```
private async Task Adding_Com(string company_ID, string company_Name, string address, string website, string contact_No, string logo)
{
    string Query = "INSERT INTO Company (Comp_ID, CompanyLogo, Comp_TelNum, Comp_Name, Comp_Address, Comp_Website) " +
                   "VALUES (@ComId, @logo, @con, @ComName, @address, @site)";

    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            using (var action = new SqlCommand(Query, conn))
            {
                action.Parameters.Add("@ComId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = company_ID;
                action.Parameters.Add("@logo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 225).Value = logo;
                action.Parameters.Add("@con", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = contact_No;
                action.Parameters.Add("@ComName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = company_Name;
                action.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = address;
                action.Parameters.Add("@site", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = website;

                conn.OpenAsync();

                try
                {
                    action.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    _ = MessageBox.Show("Company Has Been Registered");
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    _ = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
    });
}
```

The SQL table

```
CREATE TABLE Company
(
    Comp_ID VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
    CompanyLogo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Comp_TelNum VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    Comp_Name VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
    Comp_Address VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
    Comp_Website VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: should be `await action.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();` and no reason to use Task.Run

Comment: @ASh but it already in an ``await Task.Run(() => `` does that make a difference

Comment: Task.Run should not be here

Comment: Didn't see the last part of your comment

Comment: You are writing asynchronous code but do not wait its completition as @ASh pointed out. Without ````await```` the possibly delayed sql command execution might be missed AND the exception which might occured during execution will be lost too.

Comment: But I used it in other parts of the application and it still works?

Comment: The behavior would change, sometimes it will work, sometimes it won't, based on how much time the task takes to complete. To make sure it works always in a consistent manner, you should await the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` also.

Comment: `await` for completion: `await conn.OpenAsync();` and then `await action.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();`. In your case you start connecting and *foget* then start *inserting* when you haven't yet connected

Comment: @DmitryBychenko "_when you haven't yet connected_" I would say "_when you are not sure it has connected because you didn't await the`OpenAsync()`_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you should await the `OpenAsync` and the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` because if you don't, race conditions could happen and you will see nothing happens.

Your code should look similar to this:

```cs
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (var action = new SqlCommand(Query, conn))
{
    action.Parameters.Add("@ComId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = company_ID;
    action.Parameters.Add("@logo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 225).Value = logo;
    action.Parameters.Add("@con", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45).Value = contact_No;
    action.Parameters.Add("@ComName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = company_Name;
    action.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = address;
    action.Parameters.Add("@site", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = website;

    // We wait to the connection to be opened to make sure we do not work with a closed connection
    await conn.OpenAsync(); 

    try
    {
        // We wait the command to finish before claiming the data was inserted.
        await action.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); 
        _ = MessageBox.Show("Company Has Been Registered");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        _ = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```